# Javascript redirect to mobile URL# Anchor links not supported by the request

Tags: javascript, mobile, redirect, http-redirect

Am using JS function below in order to redirect index page to another one if mobile screen width is less than 600 px;
The problem that anchor links redirecting to the index pages and being initiated from other pages are not passing any anchor links to the new requested url used for the redirection.
**For example :** Index.html redirects to mobindex.html
**Now For:** Index.html**#anchor-link** redirecting just to mobindex.html**#anchor not being included**.

```
    <script>

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent)  ) {

if(screen.width >= 600){
    // Stay on desktop website
} else {
    window.location = "http://mywebsite.com/mobindex.html";
}

}
</script>
```

Did anyone had this issue before and what possible fix?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for any help...
Actually Adding 
  `+window.location.hash;` to the requested url, in that way solved problem:

```
window.location = "http://mywebsite.com/mobindex.html" +window.location.hash;
```